# this.model.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a JSON that returns from a REST API the following :

```
[
    {
        title: "Block 1",
        images: [url1, url2, url3]
    },
    {
        title: "Block 2",
        images: [url7, url8, url9]
    },
    {
        title: "Block 3",
        images: [url4, url10]
    }
]
```

On the view I want to render URLs so I can show the images on the template, for that I have the below :

index.html

```
<script id="template" type="text/template">
    <img src=<%= images %>>
</script>
```

Main.js

```
theView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#mydiv'),
    render: function() {
        var template = _.template($('#template').html());
        var html = template(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(html);
        return this;
    }

})

fetchFromServ = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "http://example.com/jsonFile.php"
})

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    var fet = new fetchFromServ();
    foo = fet.fetch();

    var view = new theView({ model: foo });
    view.render();

});
```

So far, here is what I get :

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.model.get is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var` (or ES6 variants `let` or `const`) so you won't always create implicit globals.

```
var foo = fet.fetch();
```

`fetch` returns a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) because it calls [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in the background, it doesn't return the model.

So you should instantiate your view with `fet` instead.

```
var view = new theView({ model: fet });
```

---

Also, a good convention is to capitalize "types" variable, like `TheView` or `FetchFromServer`.

---

You could replace `document.addEventListener` with [jQuery's shorthand `$(() => {})`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-callback) since you're already using jQuery.

---

Note that your template won't work with the current data you've provided.

You'd need to loop through the `images` URL array and output an `img` tag for each. For this, you should use a Backbone Collection to handle the received data.

There are already a ton of examples, tutorials, and many other answers which explain how to render a list. Here's a few of my own:

- [Simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40004457/1218980) or [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40724956/1218980)
- [Example which includes a cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40160987/1218980)
- [Advanced technique to efficiently render a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44034868/1218980)